# Django post time to database

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and trying to build a blog that will register the time the user logged in and the time the user logged out.

I'm guessing this would go in the views but I don't have a clue on how to approach the problem.

How would I go about sending the time the user logged in to the database?

Any hint and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`auth.model.User.last_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login) to get the last login time of the user, assuming you are using Django's built-in authentication:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='johndoe')
last_login = user.last_login
```

If you want to store this data somewhere else other than `User` table, you can simply insert this `last_login` to the table you want. Otherwise, it is already in `models.User`.

As for recording logging out, you can use the following view for your `logout` view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.utils import timezone

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    logout_time = timezone.now()
    # Now save your logout_time to the table you want
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

Alternatively, you can utilize Django's `user_logged_out` signal (available in Django 1.3+) to record the last logout time each time a user logs out:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out

def update_last_logout(sender, user, **kwargs):
    """
    A signal receiver which updates the last_logout date for
    the user logging out.
    """
    user.last_logout = timezone.now()
    user.save(update_fields=['last_logout'])
user_logged_out.connect(update_last_logout)
```

You can put this at the bottom of your `models.py` file. Note that the solution above assumes you would extend `User` model to include `last_logout` field. If you aren't sure how you would go about doing that, you can start from here: [Django Tip 5: Extending contrib.auth.models.User](http://www.ryanwest.info/blog/2011/django-tip-5-extending-contrib-auth-models-user/).

In fact, the second approach is exactly how Django updates `last_login` for `User`: [models.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py).

---

Reference:

1. [Official Django doc on `last_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login)
2. [Extending `contrib.auth.models.User`](http://www.ryanwest.info/blog/2011/django-tip-5-extending-contrib-auth-models-user/)